# Flat data of BigQuery table and copy the flatted data to a new BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, flatten, unnest

I'm new to BQ.
I have a table which some of the columns are record-repeated. I'm trying to flat the table, so it would be kind of relational, and to insert the flatted data into new BigQuery table. 
Is it possible? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Assume you have simple table like below

```sql
Row id  repeated_record  
--- --  ---------------
1   1   google   
        facebook     
        viant    
2   2   dell     
        hp
```

You can easily mimic it with below query

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table-with-repeated-record` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ['google', 'facebook', 'viant'] AS repeated_record UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['dell', 'hp']
)
SELECT *
FROM `table-with-repeated-record`
```

So now, to get it flatten - use below query

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table-with-repeated-record` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ['google', 'facebook', 'viant'] AS repeated_record UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['dell', 'hp']
)
SELECT id, flatted_data
FROM `table-with-repeated-record`, 
  UNNEST(repeated_record) AS flatted_data
```

result will be as below

```sql
Row id  flatted_data     
--- --  ------------
1   1   google   
2   1   facebook     
3   1   viant    
4   2   dell     
5   2   hp
```

Below is another example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table-with-repeated-record` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT<line INT64, name STRING>(1, 'google'), (2, 'facebook'), (3, 'viant')] AS repeated_record UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<line INT64, name STRING>(5, 'dell'), (6, 'hp')]
)
SELECT *
FROM `table-with-repeated-record`
```

which mimic below table

```sql
Row id  repeated_record.line    repeated_record.name     
--- --  --------------------    --------------------
1   1   1                       google   
        2                       facebook     
        3                       viant    
2   2   5                       dell     
        6                       hp
```

and way to flatten it is:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table-with-repeated-record` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [STRUCT<line INT64, name STRING>(1, 'google'), (2, 'facebook'), (3, 'viant')] AS repeated_record UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<line INT64, name STRING>(5, 'dell'), (6, 'hp')]
)
SELECT id, flatted_data.line, flatted_data.name
FROM `table-with-repeated-record`, 
  UNNEST(repeated_record) AS flatted_data
```

which ends up with

```sql
Row id  line    name     
--- --  ----    ----
1   1   1       google   
2   1   2       facebook     
3   1   3       viant    
4   2   5       dell     
5   2   6       hp
```

> do you have any idea how to do it without specify the data like ['google', 'facebook', 'viant'] etc? the size of the table is not constant, and it is changing from time to time, as well the data the is stored in the table, the only thing I know for sure is the columns

you should just use below (without dummy data that was used as an example and for you to be able to play with query)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, flatted_data.line, flatted_data.name
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable`, 
  UNNEST(repeated_record) AS flatted_data
```

Comment: thanks! do you have any idea how to do it without specify the data like ['google', 'facebook', 'viant'] etc? the size of the table is not constant, and it is changing from time to time, as well the data the is stored in the table, the only thing I know for sure is the columns.

Comment: just use your table instead of dummy data used in answer to just give you ability to play with code and get started!

Comment: so, instead of table-with-repeated-record put your real project.dataset.table

Comment: By the way, I downloaded your BQ mate. It helps me a lot!

Comment: How can I query my table and add the "id" and "line" without specify the data in columns? I think misunderstood you before.

Comment: check update in my answer. I understand you are novice - but hope now you will get this

Comment: now it is working. I'll clarify myself: I have tables with multiple repeated records. I want to query the table and get flatted data.
In order to flat the data of the table, you should use the unnest() as Mikhail explained, and in the "SELECT" clause, do not specify the "RECORD" objects.